# Pandas dataframe value where datetime between two dates in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given two dataframes:

```
print(df1)
        id    status     started              ended
0       001   green      2014-09-04 01:00:00  2014-09-05 01:49:49
1       001   green      2014-09-05 01:49:50  2014-09-08 03:49:49
2       001   orange     2014-09-08 01:49:50  2014-09-18 23:49:49
3       002   green      2014-09-03 07:00:00  2014-09-09 02:59:49
4       002   red        2014-09-09 02:59:50  2014-09-11 02:39:29
5       002   red        2014-09-11 02:39:30  2014-09-15 01:00:00

print(df2)
        id    action     action_datetime                      
0       001   process1   2014-09-07 01:49:49  
1       001   process2   2014-09-08 01:49:52  
2       001   process3   2014-09-09 10:00:00  
3       002   process1   2014-09-08 11:01:29  
4       002   process2   2014-09-09 06:59:49
```

In df2, I want to lookup corresponding `status` from df1 using df2's `id` and `action_datetime`. i.e. `status` corresponding
 to each df2 row where `df1.id` = `df2.id` and `action_datetime` between the df1's started  and ended:

```
        id    action     action_datetime      status                
0       001   process1   2014-09-07 01:49:49  green
1       001   process2   2014-09-08 01:49:52  orange
2       001   process3   2014-09-09 10:00:00  orange
3       002   process1   2014-09-08 11:01:29  green
4       002   process2   2014-09-09 06:59:49  red
```

Comment: I think you can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41020978/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael, thank you

Comment: Yes, it is really good answer, dont forget upvote ;)

Comment: very good answer, I have upvoted. I used `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: @jezrael one quick question, before performing `searchsorted`, how to first ensure `df1.id = df2.id` ? otherwise, it will `searchsorted` from any `df1['ended]` rather than `searchsorted` on `df1['ended]` only where `df1.id = df2.id`

Comment: Hmmm, I am not sure, but in [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41093367/2901002) need `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['id'])`. Maybe.

Comment: Or something like `df = df1[df1.id.isin(df2.id)]`