# Counting previous occurences of an ID in a Dataframe within a certain date range

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe containing dates of when a customer enters a shop. I'm looking for a method that will allow me to count the number of times a customer has visited a shop in the past month from the current Date_Visited including the current visit.

So, for a minimal dataset below

```
Customer_ID     Date_Visited (Year-Month-Day)
1               2020-07-10
2               2020-07-09
1               2020-01-01               
2               2020-07-08
1               2020-07-08
3               2020-07-01
```

I'm looking for an output of

```
Customer_ID     Date_Visited    visit_times
1               2020-07-10      2
2               2020-07-09      2
1               2020-01-01      1         
2               2020-07-08      1 
1               2020-07-08      1
3               2020-07-01      1
```

I've been able to use a solution involving loops - but this would be inefficient for large dataframes.

I've thought about trying to merge two copies of the dataframe and use a similar approach to that in [Counting Number of Occurrences Between Dates (Given an ID value) From Another Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56906293/counting-number-of-occurrences-between-dates-given-an-id-value-from-another-da) but I'm not sure if this method is the best way to approach this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Customer_ID` and year/month (using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) on the sorted dataframe ([`pandas.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) using the date column as `key`) and apply a [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per group (you need to add 1 as the count starts from 0 in python):

```
df['visit_times'] = (df.sort_values(by='Date_Visited (Year-Month-Day)')
                       .groupby(['Customer_ID',
                                 pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='Date_Visited (Year-Month-Day)')
                                ])
                       .cumcount()+1
                               )
```

output:

```
   Customer_ID Date_Visited (Year-Month-Day)  visit_times
0            1                    2020-07-10            2
1            2                    2020-07-09            2
2            1                    2020-01-01            1
3            2                    2020-07-08            1
4            1                    2020-07-08            1
5            3                    2020-07-01            1
```

Comment: I have learnt `pd.Grouper` today: Thank you! I have added it to my list of favorite functions. I would give +300 points if I could.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Glad it helped. You can always [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on this question in 48 hours if you really want, "reward existing answer" is [one of the reasons](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) ;)

Comment: It am not sure how that works as I am not the question author

Comment: I have also never done it, but according to the help, there should be a "start a bounty" link below the question when the question is at least 2 days old. Don't feel like you have to do it though ;)